# Tweepy on_data receiving None

Tags: python, apache-kafka, tweepy

I am following guide on how stream data to Kafka with Python

After making the modifications suggested by @MarkTolonen I am now getting the following error:

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'**

The full code is as follows:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from kafka import KafkaClient
#from kafka import SimpleProducer

access_token = ""
access_token_secret =  ""
consumer_key =  ""
consumer_secret =  ""
#Configure Kafka
kafkaBrokers = '127.0.1.1:9092'

#producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=kafkaBrokers,key_serializer=lambda k: k.encode('ascii','ignore'),value_serializer=lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))


class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        producer.send("trump", data.encode('utf-8'))
        print (data)
        return True
    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)
        
kafka = 'localhost:9092'
#kafka = KafkaClient("localhost:9092")
#producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(track="trump")
```

Comment: You're only calling `.encode` once in your code, so it seems your `on_data` method is being called with `data` set to `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer the documentation why the data could ever be None, but you can work around that like so

```
    def on_data(self, data):
        if data:
            producer.send("trump", data.encode('utf-8'))
            print (data)
            return True
        return False
```